# is the fist line comment css type declaraction still necessary?

Tags: css

When I first started learning front end development I used to see the first line comment 
/* css document */ 

or something to that extent, I can't remember what it was...

I haven't used it recently. Is it even necessary anymore?

Was that just a dreamweaver thing?

Could having your first line of css as a comment be dangerous?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to learn how to format your posts.

Comment: It's never been necessary, optional maybe. And as a comment, no, not dangerous.

Comment: It never was required for "normal" CSS stylesheets. Check with other systems (e.g. DreamWeaver) and specific requirements they impose.

Answer (score 3):

CSS doesn't need any declaration like HTML documents do need DOCTYPES (well they don't need them but it's highly recommended)

Having a comment as first line in your CSS isn't dangerous at all. (In fact WordPress themes requires this, but that's something completely else)

Answer (score 0):

You never have. From what I recall, the first line css comment was a, somewhat unnecessary, feature of dreamweaver at some point. Its only purpose was to remind the user that they were writing a css file, which was only necessary because dreamweaver would automatically save the document as .css if you clicked New>CSS File.